# Retrieve current SQL Server version

Tags: sql

How do I get only the SQL Server release version?

```
select @@version
```

retrieves the full information, in my case :

> *Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0 (X64)  Apr 22 2011 19:23:43  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Developer Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)*

I need only `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2`.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT 
    SERVERPROPERTY('Edition'),
    SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')
```

I get this output:

```
Developer Edition (64-bit)  10.50.2500.0
```

Based on the `ProductVersion` , you could do a "translation" to a human-readable SQL Server version name...

```
11.xx   --> SQL Server 2012
10.50.  --> SQL Server 2008 R2
10.00.  --> SQL Server 2008
09.xx   --> SQL Server 2005
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [SERVERPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx)

For example

```
select SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')
```

returns 10.50.2500.0 for SQL Server 2008 R2.

There are many other values you can retrieve using SERVERPROPERTY.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@@VERSION,0,CHARINDEX('-',@@VERSION,0))
```

Gives (for me)

```
`Microsoft SQL Server 2012`
```